# Jquery scroll 1 div with elements

Tags: jquery, scroll

For jQuery I am looking for a scroller that scrolls one div from right to left. Inside the div there will be an image of 3000px in width and some hidden elements that will show with a mouse over on specific positions of the image. This will have to loop.

When searching around I only came across scrollers that have multiple images.

Does anyone know if there is a script like this around ? Or how I can make this myself with little experience in jQuery ?

Answer (score 1):

I have always liked the jQuery tools collection.

http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html

The scroller can do what you need.